# Is it possible to save a GameObject with its components in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, serialization, save, load

I'm trying to Save/Serialize a GameObject and its components (with their current values), but I don't think it's possible, any ideas ???

Keep in mind that I don't wanna use an asset from the assets store, I wanna code it myself.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can't serialize a gameobject. Just serialize the values from components attached to that gameobject. This means you must create a script that holds your important game variables you want to be able to serialize and de-serialize. That script should not inherit from `MonoBehaviour`.

Comment: The variables types in my case can not be serialized tho, that's the issue...

Comment: What are the variable types?

Comment: a variables referencing some other classes for example...

Comment: Like my first comment said, a class **can** be serialized but it must not inherit from `MonoBehaviour`.

Comment: The class I'm trying to save is inheriting from ScriptableObject, But I don't wanna save it with its default values, the values can be changed while playing so I wanna save it with the new values

Comment: The class also has references to some GameObjects...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I dont have the rep to make a comment. I use two methods to acheive this save state.
First is what programmer seems to suggest, make a class that hosts the property's needed to recreate the object. Component names can be saved as strings, then fetched using 
`gameObject.AddComponent(Type.GetType(componentName));` 
If you are doing this alot it may be worth checking out this forum first.[Here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/addcomponent-based-on-string-or-alternative-solved.462984/)

You can serialize these classes using the unity serializer(the string names of types will serialise. You may have to make a sub class to handle the values in each object of different type.

This can be a fairly complicated approach so I prefer a file path serialized for a prefab in the resources folder. Any values that need saving can be saved in a serializable class like first approach which is referenced in a script on the saved prefab. This script has a method to apply all details saved in the deserialized class to the prefab when it is created. The details are captured by the script,added to the class and serialized whenever the object state should be recorded.

The exact way this is managed may vary but I have done this myself with he ability to store any values I could need. Even if you use a third party serializer from the asset store you will still have trouble saving entire objects, but you will be able to get enough info to recreate.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to save the components I want (custom scripts) by saving them in a json file, then serializing them with binary so they can be more secure.
Thanks to everyone who tried to help tho...